# Can we say that $m$ is $\sigma$-additive?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space.

Let $f\in \mathcal{L}_{\mathbb{R}}^1$ and $m:\mathcal{A}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that :

> (1). $m(A\cup B)=m(A)+m(B)$ for all $A, B\in \mathcal{A}$ such that $A\cap B=\emptyset$.
>
> (2). $|m(A)|\le \int_{A} |f(t)| d\mu(t)$  for all $A\in \mathcal{A}$

Can we say that $m$ is $\sigma$-additive ?

an idea please.

Answer (score 1):

First, consider a sequence $\langle A_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\rangle$ with $A_n\supset A_{n+1}$ and $\bigcap_n A_n=\emptyset$. Then
$$
|m(A_n)|\le \int_{A_n}|f|d\mu \underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0
$$
by standard measure theoretic facts.

Now, let $\langle D_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\rangle$ be pairwise disjoint with $D=\bigcup_n D_n$. Put $B_n=\bigcup_{i<n}D_i$ and $A_n=D\setminus B_n$. Then the $A_n$ form a sequence which decreases to $0$, so that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} m(A_n)=0
$$
On the other hand, by finite additivity, 
$$
m(A_n)=m(D)-m(B_n)=m(D)-\sum_{i<n}m(D_i)
$$
Therefore
$$
m(D)=\sum_i m(D_i)
$$